# Merge feature to two branches

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request, git-flow

I work on a project, that uses Gitflow as a Workflow. And we use the onpremise TFS server, as our Git server.

I had to make a hotfix for some released code, so I made a hotfix branch based on the master branch.
Here I added my fix, pushed the hotfix branch to origin, and made a pull-request from this hotfix branch, to the master branch.

Since this flaw also exists in the development branch, I cherry picked the PR and merged it to develop aswell.

Is this the right procedure for handling this?

My reason for asking is that, technically the changes are merged into both branches, but TFS believes the two branches aren't equal, because the SHA1 hash on the commits are different.

So the same commit is merged into both branches, but the commit ids are different.

Is my workflow wrong, or is there something I haven't considered?

When merging the pull-requests I do not select Squash.

Comment: Instead of cherry picking and merging into development why not merge changes from master into development branch so that it's not a separate commit id.

Comment: @asolanki I thought about that too, and the only reason I haven't done it that way, was that TFS showed me a Cherry-Pick button, so I thought they were trying to guide me towards the "right" workflow. I guess a simple merge is the correct way to go. My only concern is that I cannot merge two branches on TFS, but that is a tooling problem imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gitflow documentation from Atlassian recommend the below workflow after you have finished the fixes in hotfix branch

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix_branch
git checkout develop
git merge hotfix_branch
git branch -D hotfix_branch
```

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
So in summary there should be no cherry picking from one branch to another instead the changes should get merged from the hotfix to both master and develop branch.

Comment: Can we agree on that I make a PR from hotfix to master, and merge from master to develop?

Comment: Yes but the only caveat being master does not have any additional changes which you don't want to bring to develop.